# How to find user from websocket request?

Tags: django, django-channels

In django channels 2.1.2 we can get the authenticated logged in user by following:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
     async def websocket_connect(self,event):
        logged_in_user = self.scope['user']
```

How do i find logged in user in case of channels 1.1.8 when inheriting WebsocketConsumer from channels.generic.websockets

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        logged_in_user = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after reading the django channels documentation i have got the answer.Here is the link to documentation https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/generics.html#sessions-and-users

**Sessions and Users**

If you wish to use channel_session or channel_session_user with a class-based consumer, simply set one of the variables in the class body:

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    channel_session_user = True
```

This will run the appropriate decorator around your handler methods, and provide message.channel_session and message.user on the message object - both the one passed in to your handler as an argument as well as self.message, as they point to the same instance.

And if you just want to use the user from the django session, add http_user:

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    http_user = True
```

This will give you message.user, which will be the same as request.user would be on a regular View.

And if you want to use both user and session from the django session, add http_user_and_session:

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    http_user_and_session = True
```

This will give you message.user and message.http_session.

**hence in this case we can find the logged in user as:**

```
class ChatConsumer(WebscoketConsumer):
    http_user=True
    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        logged_in_user = message.user
```